# oracle apex email and sms authentication

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to Create a user screen with Two authentications (SMS and Email)
User will receive email to verify and activate his account first.
After that he set password and he will receive SMS massage to verify the password.I want to do this in Oracle apex.I have tried Custom Authentication but i didn't found fruitful, Any one have some good idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

after u take care of the email and sms verification, u should store that data in the data base and create a function to use in your custom authentication that verifies if the user is already validated.

put the function in shared components -> authentication schemes -> settings -> Authentication Function Name

(the function must return true or false to allow the login)

Comment: How can I send a URL to User email and After User click the User should be activated in database

Comment: @Cost do you have any example for same scenerio

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of using SMS for Two-Factor Authentication, but if you must, perhaps this might demo implementation for Time-based One Time Password (TOTP) might give you some ideas: https://github.com/fuzziebrain/orclapex-tfa-demo

I provided some background information here as well: https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/1718/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this in one of my APEX project but only with the e-mail. For the sms I use it in another context but you could still do it. You will need a smtp server ( you can run one on your server ) and for the sms you will need an external provider. In your oracle database, create a table called OTP ( one time password ).

This table contains a foreign key to a user. When the user creates an account, run a dynamic action in pl/sql that will generate a random 6 digit number that will be encrypt in your OTP table. This dynamic action will also send an email to the user with APEX_MAIL. The full documentation for how to use APEX-MAIL is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_mail.htm#AEAPI341) and it is pretty easy to use. You can send the user the password for authentication trough email.

Create a new session user called user_na (not authenticated) and make it so that when he connects, the only page he can see is a page with a text field to enter the password he receive through email. After he enters it, encrypt it the same way you did when he created an account and compare the password in the OTP table. If they match , change his account type to user and then he will be able to access every page that you made accessible for the users.

If you also want to send an sms, I recommend using this [tutorial](https://www.google.ca/amp/www.inside-oracle-apex.com/sending-sms-to-mobile-phone/amp/). The sms provider have a free trial if you want to test. If you have any questions don’t hesitate to ask I can easily help you with this.

**NOTE**: if you don’t want to create different session_users you can just add a column in your user table named authenticated. Set it to 0 by default and to 1 when he enters the email password. Then, when he log in, check if this value is 0 or 1 to know which page you should redirect him to.